# tailwindcss : from-muted/10 from-10% to-muted/30 to-50%

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

```
  return (
    <div className="fixed inset-x-0 bottom-0 bg-red-100 bg-gradient-to-b from-muted/10 from-10% to-muted/30 to-50%">
      <ButtonScrollToBottom />

      </div>
    </div>
  )
```

what does 'from-muted/10 from-10% to-muted/30 to-50%' mean ?
I didn't get anything from google and tailwindcss web .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from-muted/10` is a color stop for the gradient `bg-gradient-to-b`. `muted` would be a [custom color in the Tailwind configuration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-custom-colors) this code is from. `/10` is an [opacity modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity) for the color, setting the alpha channel to `0.1` opacity.

`from-10%` is [the position of the `from-*` color stop](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gradient-color-stops#specifying-stop-positions), `10%`.

`to-muted/30` is the end color stop for the gradient, with `0.3` opacity modifier. `to-50%` means the end color stop is positioned at `50%`.

To translate this back to vanilla CSS:

```css
selector {
  background-image: linear-gradient( /* bg-gradient-to-b */
    to bottom,                       /* bg-gradient-to-b */
    rgb(<color> / 0.1) /* from-muted/10 */ 10% /* from-10% */,
    rgb(<color> / 0.3) /* to-muted/30 */   50% /* to-50% */
  );
}

without-annotations {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgb(<color> / 0.1) 10%,
    rgb(<color> / 0.3) 50%
  );
}
```